# Entity framework: добавление нового обьекта

Tags: entity-framework, .net

Всем доброго времени суток.

Задача: в модели есть 4 объекта (допустим, продукты, новости, кирпичи, бананы), нужно осуществить crud. Вопрос: как это можно сделать с помощью обобщенных классов? Чтобы не в каждом объекте делать crud, а все вынести в обобщенный класс.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно, нашел решение кому интересно. Если есть предложения еще, пишите.

[Creating a Generic Entity Framework 4.0 Repository](https://web.archive.org/web/20201025102958/http://geekswithblogs.net/seanfao/archive/2009/12/03/136680.aspx)